# Passing parameter to sh file from java class

Tags: java, shell, sh

I have a method in java to execute a shell script in ubuntu.

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "startdomain.sh"};
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

startdomain.sh is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
gksudo -P "/home/priyatam/glassfish-4.0/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain domain1"
```

I need to pass the domain name (here domain1) as parameter from java class.
How to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be able to pass an argument like you normally would on the command line:

```
String domain1 = "some domain name";
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "startdomain.sh " + domain1};
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Then change startdomain.sh so that it puts an argument where `domain1` current is:

```
#!/bin/sh
gksudo -P "/home/priyatam/glassfish-4.0/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain $1"
```

Comment: @PriyatamRoy You can mark the answer as correct so the next person knows this answer is the solution to the problem